# Ordenar lista ligada em C

Tags: c, struct, classificação, lista-encadeada

O meu problema envolve ler dados de um arquivo texto, onde é fornecido o CPF,nome,email,idade, ordenar guardar usando lista ordenar em ordem crescente através da idade, caso tiver idade igual ordenar por cpf. Porém estou com dificuldade em ordenar a lista ligada, até agora fiz isso

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Dado{
    char CPF[12];
    char nome[41];
    char email[31];
    int idade;
    struct Dado* proximo;
}Dado;

int ler_string_arq(FILE* arq, char *campo_destino){
    int letra = 0;
    char ch;
    if (fscanf(arq,"%c",&ch) == EOF)
    {
        return 1;       
    }
    while( ch != ',') 
    {
        campo_destino[letra] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        letra++;
    }
    campo_destino[letra] = '\0';
return 0;
}

int main()
{
FILE *arq, *arqout;
char ch,teste;

arq = fopen("read.txt","r");

Dado *inicio = NULL, *fim = NULL;

while (1)
{
    Dado *pessoa = malloc(sizeof(Dado));
    pessoa->proximo = NULL;
    if (inicio == NULL){
        inicio = pessoa;
    }
    if (fim != NULL){

        fim->proximo = pessoa;
    }
    fim = pessoa;

    if (ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->CPF)){
        free(pessoa);
        break;
    }
    ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->nome);
    ler_string_arq(arq,pessoa->email);
    fscanf(arq,"%d", &pessoa->idade);
    fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
}
fclose(arq);


arqout = fopen("write.txt","w");
Dado* pessoa = inicio;
while (pessoa->idade != 0){
    fprintf(arqout,"%s,%s,%s,%d\n", pessoa->CPF, pessoa->nome, pessoa->email, pessoa->idade);
    pessoa= pessoa->proximo;
}
fclose(arqout);
return 0;
}
```

Estou começando a estudar listas, alguém poderia indicar uma boa maneira de ordenar oq já fiz e como isso alteraria o print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ordenando com cópia de valores

A forma mais simplificada de o demonstrar para o código que tem é através de um algoritmo tipo o *bubble sort* com a copia dos valores de cada estrutura entre si. A diferença dá se maioritariamente no percorrer da lista, que é feito através dos ponteiros `proximo`.

Implementação:

```
Dado *pessoa1 = inicio;

while (pessoa1 != NULL){
    Dado *pessoa2 = pessoa1->proximo;
    while (pessoa2 != NULL){
        if (pessoa1->idade > pessoa2->idade){ //se maior troca o conteudo das duas pessoas
            int temp_idade = pessoa1->idade; 
            pessoa1->idade = pessoa2->idade;
            pessoa2->idade = temp_idade;
            troca_string(pessoa1->CPF, pessoa2->CPF, 12);
            troca_string(pessoa1->nome, pessoa2->nome, 41);
            troca_string(pessoa1->email, pessoa2->email, 31);
        }
        pessoa2 = pessoa2->proximo;
    }

    pessoa1 = pessoa1->proximo;
}
```

O primeiro `while` percorre a lista do inicio ao fim, e o segundo `while` vai a percorrer mais à frente e sempre que achar uma pessoa com uma idade maior faz a troca de todos os valores dessa pessoa. Como existem várias strings a serem trocadas optei por criar uma função que faz a troca de string até uma determinada quantidade de carateres de forma a simplificar. Como apenas havia um campo do tipo inteiro a ser trocado não fiz nenhuma função para essa troca.

A função `troca_string` seria:

```
void troca_string(char *str1, char *str2, size_t tamanho){
    static char temp[50];
    memcpy(temp, str1, tamanho);
    memcpy(str1, str2, tamanho);
    memcpy(str2, temp, tamanho);
}
```

Neste caso o `static` evita que a string `temp` seja cria toda a vez que a função é chamada, e passa a ser criada apenas uma vez, que é o ideal para este cenário. Para a troca da string em si utilizei a função [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) que já existe para copiar a string toda, mas podia ter feito o mesmo à custa de um *loop* normal copiando letra a letra.

Esta implementação apesar de funcionar não é muito boa pois a troca de cada elemento da estrutura é bem pesada. Na minha máquina o `sizeof(Dado)` dá 92, que são 92 bytes, o que significa que cada troca tem de copiar 92 bytes 3 vezes. E pode ainda ser pior dependendo da quantidade e tamanho dos campos da estrutura, assim como da quantidade de elementos a ordenar. A solução a este problema é ponteiros.

### Ordenando por troca de ponteiro

Com troca de ponteiros conseguimos evitar a copia dos vários valores, mas esta solução regra geral implica mudar a estrutura original e consequentemente grande parte do código e por isso torna-se um pouco chata.

Neste caso a estrutura passaria a ter um ponteiro para os dados e outro para o próximo nó da lista como já tinha anteriormente:

```
typedef struct Info { //informação de cada pessoa
    char CPF[12];
    char nome[41];
    char email[31];
    int idade;
} Info;

typedef struct Dado {
    Info* info; //agora ponteiro em vez de os campos diretamente
    struct Dado* proximo;
} Dado;
```

A estrutura `Dado` corresponde na verdade a cada nó da lista ao passo que a estrutura `Info` corresponde às informações de cada pessoa.

Com esta alteração a leitura das informações do arquivo teria que ser diferente pois não só tem de alocar também espaço para o `Info` como a leitura tem de passar a ser sobre o `Info`:

```
int main() {
    ... 
    Dado *inicio = NULL, *fim = NULL;

    while (1) {
        Dado *pessoa = malloc(sizeof(Dado));
        pessoa->info = malloc(sizeof(Info)); //alocar também o info

        pessoa->proximo = NULL;
        if (inicio == NULL) {
            inicio = pessoa;
        }
        if (fim != NULL) {
            fim->proximo = pessoa;
        }

        if (ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->info->CPF)) { //agora ->info->CPF
            free(pessoa->info); //liberar tambem o info
            free(pessoa);
            fim->proximo = NULL;
            break;
        }
        fim = pessoa;

        ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->info->nome); //->info->nome
        ler_string_arq(arq,pessoa->info->email); //->info->email
        fscanf(arq,"%d", &pessoa->info->idade); //->info->idade
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    }
    fclose(arq);
```

A ordenação agora fica mais simples e mais eficiente pois quando é necessário trocar duas pessoas de ordem, basta trocar o ponteiro para as informações de cada nó:

```
Dado *pessoa1 = inicio;

while (pessoa1 != NULL){
    Dado *pessoa2 = pessoa1->proximo;
    while (pessoa2 != NULL){
        if (pessoa1->info->idade > pessoa2->info->idade){
            Info *temp = pessoa1->info; //agora troca só o info
            pessoa1->info = pessoa2->info;
            pessoa2->info = temp;
        }
        pessoa2 = pessoa2->proximo;
    }

    pessoa1 = pessoa1->proximo;
}
```

No mostrar também tem de trocar para `->info`:

```
arqout = fopen("write.txt","w");
Dado* pessoa = inicio;
while (pessoa != NULL) {
    fprintf(arqout,"%s,%s,%s,%d\n", pessoa->info->CPF, pessoa->info->nome, pessoa->info->email, pessoa->info->idade);
    pessoa= pessoa->proximo;
}
fclose(arqout);
```

Código completo para referência:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Info {
    char CPF[12];
    char nome[41];
    char email[31];
    int idade;
} Info;

typedef struct Dado {
    Info* info;
    struct Dado* proximo;
} Dado;

int ler_string_arq(FILE* arq, char *campo_destino) {
    int letra = 0;
    char ch;
    if (fscanf(arq,"%c",&ch) == EOF) {
        return 1;
    }
    while( ch != ',') {
        campo_destino[letra] = ch;
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
        letra++;
    }
    campo_destino[letra] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE *arq, *arqout;
    char ch,teste;

    arq = fopen("read.txt","r");

    Dado *inicio = NULL, *fim = NULL;

    while (1) {
        Dado *pessoa = malloc(sizeof(Dado));
        pessoa->info = malloc(sizeof(Info));

        pessoa->proximo = NULL;
        if (inicio == NULL) {
            inicio = pessoa;
        }
        if (fim != NULL) {

            fim->proximo = pessoa;
        }

        if (ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->info->CPF)) {
            free(pessoa->info);
            free(pessoa);
            fim->proximo = NULL;
            break;
        }
        fim = pessoa;

        ler_string_arq(arq, pessoa->info->nome);
        ler_string_arq(arq,pessoa->info->email);
        fscanf(arq,"%d", &pessoa->info->idade);
        fscanf(arq,"%c", &ch);
    }
    fclose(arq);

    Dado *pessoa1 = inicio;

    while (pessoa1 != NULL){
        Dado *pessoa2 = pessoa1->proximo;
        while (pessoa2 != NULL){
            if (pessoa1->info->idade > pessoa2->info->idade){
                Info *temp = pessoa1->info;
                pessoa1->info = pessoa2->info;
                pessoa2->info = temp;
            }
            pessoa2 = pessoa2->proximo;
        }

        pessoa1 = pessoa1->proximo;
    }

    arqout = fopen("write.txt","w");
    Dado* pessoa = inicio;
    while (pessoa != NULL) {
        fprintf(arqout,"%s,%s,%s,%d\n", pessoa->info->CPF, pessoa->info->nome, pessoa->info->email, pessoa->info->idade);
        pessoa= pessoa->proximo;
    }
    fclose(arqout);
    return 0;
}
```